# Not able to join to #temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I'm pulling over a result set from a different server into a temp table, using the following syntax:

```
SELECT *
into #temp
FROM OPENQUERY ([SOURCESERVERNAME], 'Select statement here')
```

I'm then trying to join this #temp table into another query on a DIFFERENT server, but it's not accessible. I'm assuming this is because the temp table was built in memory on the SOURCE server, and not the destination server I'm trying to use it on?

How do I get around this? I do not have the ability to link servers.

Comment: The temp table is on disk in `tempdb` but is accessible only to the spid that created it. Why not just create a permanent table in tempDB, you can access that from any connection then.

Comment: because I do not have the security to do so.

Comment: Can you use a `##global` temp table?

Comment: I don't know what that is.

Comment: `SELECT * into ##temp FROM...`

Comment: I get the same "could not be bound" error. Based on a quick google search, making a table global just allows it to be seen by other sessions, not servers.

Comment: @user2938667 `making a table global just allows it to be seen by other sessions, not servers`. How do you think your 'other server' queries the server that your temp table is being created at? Via establishing a session on that server. A global temp table is accessible by all sessions on the server, so that would work. Your issue is likely just he persistence of the object. To quote Microsoft `Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them.` So if this all needs to be on disk you need a real table

Comment: @user2938667 or a way to for the global temp table to be retained by the session that created it or another transaction that is using the object. Otherwise the global temp table will likely be gone by the time that your 'other server' spins up its query and actually submits the query.

Comment: Please show your full code. You can join it, but it would need to be on this server, you cannot join it inside of `OPENQUERY`